# Alternative to #using <System.dll> in an Unmanaged C++ application?

Tags: c++, unmanaged, managed, managed-c++

I need to use a certain managed C++ API in an unmanaged application.

The managed API is this:

```
#using <System.dll>

auto activeUdpListeners = System::Net::NetworkInformation::IPGlobalProperties::GetIPGlobalProperties()->GetActiveUdpListeners();
```

Now I need to have this kind of code in an unmanaged C++ application. I cannot have Common Language Runtime (CLR) support. Is there an equivalent to the following line in unmanaged C++?

```
#using <System.dll> // E1943: "#using" requires C++/CLI mode.
```

The farthest I could think of is this:

```
#include <stdlib.h> /* system, NULL, EXIT_FAILURE */
```

But it does not seem to contain std::system::net::... It appears to be used for a different purpose.

How can I access this API in an unmanaged C++ application?

Thank you.

Comment: `GetActiveUdpListeners` is a managed function, you can't call that directly from unmanaged code. I believe you can retrieve the same information via the native [GetExtendedUdpTable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/iphlpapi/nf-iphlpapi-getextendedudptable) function.

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/DatagramSocket

Comment: @VictorGubin: Thank you for the link. I'll try to set it up and give it a shot.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError: Thank you for the suggestion. Is there a sample online? I could not find a single one for some reason. Thanks.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError: Your advice gave me a great head start. Thank you. I was able to find the sample using the "GetExtendedUdpTable" keyword you suggested, and it was exactly what I needed. I've attached the link below. When you get a chance, could you please post your comment as an Answer, along with the link I've provided, and I'll mark it as accepted? (Hopefully that'll encourage people to reverse their downvote for my question ^_^...) Link: https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/blob/master/Samples/Win7Samples/netds/iphelp/ipstat/IPStat.Cpp

Comment: @Stout: As this was just a quick API lookup on my part, I believe a better resolution would be if you post an answer yourself featuring a small sample using the function.